# Rolling With Additional Batch ignored during elastic beanstalk app update

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

We're using a bitbucket pipeline to deploy a NodeJS app to elastic beanstalk (eb).
We've configured the eb environment option "Rolling updates and deployments" to use "Rolling with additional batch" (RollingWithAdditionalBatch strategy).
This used to work fine up until about a year ago or so, since then (and updating the platform version to Node 14 then 16), the "rolling with additional batch" strategy is ignored on deployment. Eb seems to revert to a "rolling" strategy instead.

Bitbucket pipe version: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:1.0.2.
Eb config is as per attached screenshot.
[image]